# How to force nz-input-number to change model onkeypress not onblur?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I need to update data while user typing inside `nz-input-number`. On normal `<input>` model changes that way by default. Maybe I missed an option to do this...
I made an example to illustrate the difference between nz-input-number and raw input.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvf5yn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in option to do that, regarding to ng-zorro docs:

> Note：InputNumber will validate the input value only when (blur) and (keydown.enter) happened other than when user input character to avoid error ngModelChange output (-0.02001 or -1.0e28)

**EDIT:**

You can add your own `EventListener` and trigger `blur` or `keydown.enter` on this input, but I think it will be a bad practice.

Comment: Ah I see now that note in docs. Could be a little bigger and brighter like a warning...
They definitely should do this behavior optional, especially as we already have `ngModelOptions.updateOn` already for this.

Comment: They actually have a discussion on github about this https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/3039
No idea about results cause it almost all in chinese...

Answer (score 0):

I use :

```
<nz-input-number #myInput (keyup)="myInput.onBlur()"></nz-input-number>
```